# Safe external program execution with OCaml

Tags: unix, ocaml

Is it possible to somehow avoid the hanging OCaml program if the external program called stuck, or suddenly asking for the input (because of some error).

For example I use 7zip for unpacking archive data of different formats with this code:

```
let exec_un7zip ~dpath ~fpath =
    let cmdline = "7z x -aoa -o \"" ^ dpath ^ "\" \"" ^ fpath ^ "\"" in
    Printf.printf "exec (%s)\n" cmdline;
    let stdout = Core.Unix.open_process_in cmdline in
    Core.In_channel.input_all stdout |> ignore;
    stdout
```

Is it possible to have a timeout or other way to finish the execution here if 7zip stuck on some error or asking for additional input despite the provided flags?

Answer (score 2):

OCaml's standard (with the `Sys` module) and `Unix` libraries provides two functions that should do the trick. There are probably equivalent/higher level functions in `Core`, since you seem to use it, but I haven't checked that:

- `Unix.alarm n` will raise signal `sigalrm` after `n` seconds
- `Sys.signal Sys.sigalrm (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> do_something()))` will run `do_something()` each time `Sys.sigalrm` is raised. For instance calling `Unix.kill` on the appropriate process. In addition `Sys.signal` returns the old handler for the given signal, so that you can reinstate it afterwards.

A very crude and not thorougly tested example would be like that:

```
let cmd_timeout cmd args timeout =
  let pid = Unix.create_process cmd args Unix.stdin Unix.stdout Unix.stderr in
  let kill _ = Unix.kill pid Sys.sigterm in
  let old = Sys.signal Sys.sigalrm (Sys.Signal_handle kill) in
  let _ = Unix.alarm timeout in
  try
    let _, res = Unix.waitpid [] pid in
    (match res with
     | Unix.WEXITED d ->
       Printf.printf "Exited with status %d\n%!" d
     | Unix.WSIGNALED d ->
       Printf.printf "Signalled with %d\n%!" d
     | Unix.WSTOPPED d ->
       Printf.printf "Stopped with %d\n%!" d);
    Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm old
  with Unix.Unix_error(Unix.EINTR, _, _) ->
    Printf.printf "Timeout!\n%!"; Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm old

let () = cmd_timeout "sleep" [| "sleep"; "10" |] 3 (* will timeout *)

let () = cmd_timeout "sleep" [| "sleep"; "3" |] 10 (* will exit normally *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Async](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/async_unix/Async_unix/Process/) and [Lwt](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/3.2.1/api/Lwt_process) libraries provide modules for managing external processes without blocking the spawning process.

Comment: Thanks for the information. From the Lwt docs: "All the following functions take an optional argument timeout. If specified, after expiration, the process will be sent a Unix.sigkill signal and channels will be closed."

Answer (score 0):

I think if you allocate a pseudo tty and use that for stdin then you can catch the command reading from stdin. Otherwise the best you can do is start the command in the background and kill it when it takes too long (without outputing something).